# When a user is changing his password, is there any reason to prohibit him from using any password that he may have used in the past?

Tags: passwords

I am implementing forgot password feature for my website, and while looking at other websites for best practices, I found that gmail enforces this, no other site I looked at enforced this constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of rather out-dated ideas about passwords and password security.

If a user has a password compromised -- and then however many days later they change it -- the attacker is now blocked from the system.

Should that user ever go back and re-use his old password, then the hacker might decide to retry that account/password and regain entry into the system.

Of course, it opens up a whole new set of problems.  Make it so a user can't remember his password and they will start writing them on sticky notes taped to their monitor.

Personally? On all the sites I've worked on, I've never thought it important to add password expiration /or/ limits on what passwords may be (re)-used.

Comment: Thanks, Yes the fact that a hacker may decide to retry the account/password seems to be the only point that will be blocked by this. OTOH, it may result in usability problems for users whose accounts havent been compromised, but who want to reuse their old passwords.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought it provides little to no added security. You are trusting the user to not lose their password but I guess it can go both ways.

If they have to choose a new password then they may have to write it down or be more likely to forget it again however if they have a new password it is less likely that someone who knows a password they use could use it to access your website.

Either way make sure you are storing the hashed password for comparison and not plain text.